# How to fadeIn and fadeOut any element on clicking document's body and a specified element both?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors

### Hello Guys!

I have been trying to create a fadeIn and fadeOut menu, but it does not seem to be working at all! See the problem is when I click on the my trigger element (`div`) which classed `example`
it should be fading in the element (`div`) classed `element_obj` but if the user's click on the body element when the `element_obj` (`div`) is faded in. But when I click on my trigger element for an instance my `element_obj` (`div`) fades in and in another moment it is fade out! I know that this is the problem because I have put my body element also as a fading out trigger! But if I don't do that my whole effect is **dead**! Here is the jQuery code that I created ~~~~~~~~~

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('div#example').click(function () {

      if($('div#example_obj').is(':visible')){
            $('div#example_obj').fadeOut();
      }else{
            $('div#example_obj').fadeIn();
      }

  });
    $(document).click(function () {

      if($('div#example_obj').is(':visible')){
            $('div#example_obj').fadeOut();
      }

    });
});
```

Can anyone help me out with this.

**[PROBLEM DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/divinemamgai/UkLBh/)**

### Thanks in Advance!

---

As you can see in this demo my above problem is solved but a new problem have arise! Now I want the drop-down menu to be appear on click on it. I mean if the user clicks on the drop-down menu it does not fades out as it is now. Please see the below demo to see this new problem~~~~~~~~~~~

**[PROBLEM 2 DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/divinemamgai/UxQNV/)**

Hope you guys can help me out with this one too.

### Thanks in Advance!

---

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because the click event on div#example is bubbled up to the body element and
hence the target element fades in by the div#example and subsequently the body click handler is also executed.
You need to stop the event propagation of the div#example to retain the fadeIn

Change the div#example click handler to as below:

```
$('div#example').click(function (e) {        
    if($('div#example_obj').is(':visible')){             
        $('div#example_obj').fadeOut();       
    }else{             
        $('div#example_obj').fadeIn();       
    }    
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: +1 for readable code. *That's* what `.stopPropagation()` is for!

Comment: Thanks for previous answer to this question but now I need another help of yours with this new problem, please see it and help me out.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Ok I got the answer. Thanks for your help once again.

Comment: Am not sure if I followed your question. Made a change to the jsfiddle post. Check the one @ http://jsfiddle.net/UxQNV/1/ and let me know if this is what you meant?

Answer (score 0):

This might work. It's ugly...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).click(function(e) {
      if (e.targetElement.id == 'example')
      {
        if($('div#example_obj').is(':visible')){
            $('div#example_obj').stop().fadeOut();
        }else{
            $('div#example_obj').stop().fadeIn();
        }
      } else {
        if($('div#example_obj').is(':visible')){
            $('div#example_obj').stop().fadeOut();
        }
      }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your event is bubbling up through both event listeners. When you click on `$('div#example')`, you are also clicking on the `document`, so both are firing. You need to prevent the event propagation. Change the first event handler to:

```
$('div#example').click(function (e) {
  e.stopPropagation();

  if($('div#example_obj').is(':visible')){             
    $('div#example_obj').fadeOut();       
  }else{             
    $('div#example_obj').fadeIn();       
  }    

});
```